# How to configure the MAX31865 IC for PT100/PT1000 on the fly?

Tags: max31865

The [MAX31865](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX31865.pdf) is an RTD to digital converter IC. I want to measure both PT100 and PT1000 on the fly without changing REF resistor.
A 430ohm resistor is need for PT100 and a 4.3kohm resistor is need for PT1000.

I want to design a circuit that is capable of measuring both PT100 and PT1000 without soldering another REF resistor. How can I make an extra circuit or something for this purpose?

[image]

Comment: Looks like current trough that resistor is always flowing in the same direction, from BIAS to Isensor. You could try switching between multiple resistors using a small MOSFET like 2N7002. If the couple of ohm on resistance does not affect your required precision too much.

Comment: Can you post an example circuit?

Comment: Example borads use %0.1 tolerance resistors. I'm not sure RDS of Mosfets can stay constant?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an analog SPDT switch (or a SPST switch with the 4.3K paralleled).

For example, the [NLAS5223](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nlas5223c-d.pdf)

[image]

You should do a detailed calculation of the effects of series resistance, series resistance variation (eg. with temperature) and leakage and compare it with your error budget.

Alternately, a small telecom-style relay, preferably a bistable type to minimize thermal EMFs, could be used. Resistance and leakage will not likely be of concern but the driving is a bit more complex and contact reliability may be of issue under some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. R<sub>REF</sub> is not referenced to ground or VDD so this isn't going to be easy.*

The datasheet opening paragraph says:

> The MAX31865 is an easy-to-use resistance-to-digital converter optimized for platinum resistance temperature detectors (RTDs). An external resistor sets the sensitivity for the RTD being used and a precision delta-sigma ADC **converts the ratio of the RTD resistance to the reference resistance** into digital form.

... so you have to use the 430 Ω or 4300 Ω reference as appropriate.

If a jumper was an option the sensible approach might be to put both in with the jumper selecting which to use. An alternative would be to solder in the 4300 Ω resistor with a jumper connecting a 477.77 Ω resistor in parallel (the combination giving 430 Ω) - but where are you going to get one of those?

I don't think you're going to find an easy solution to this due to the precision required for the reference and the fact that neither end of R<sub>REF</sub> is connected to ground.

A miniature relay is probably your best option.

Comment: If it needs to be switchable electronically, an electromechanical DPDT relay would probably work too. Make sure it's rated for low-current use; you probably want one with gold or rhodium contacts, not tungsten.